# I can't find the files required to have these `using` directives functional

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on blending the essentials from the MySQL.NET driver into my application (embedded), and have come across several `using` declarations which I am unable to locate the required dll from .NET framework to add to references :

```
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Foundation;
```

I am using a winforms project in c# . I am using 4.5 framework (also tried 4.6).

What do I need to add to references to make these things available ??

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) doesn't work from where you are?

Comment: What are the classes that require these namespaces?

Comment: @KenWhite - MSDN does not show what DLL to reference. MSDN just shows blah blah about how `Windows.Networking` is part of `Windows.Networking`.  It starts to get especially nasty when trying to see some obscure `using` that requires something of a completely different naming convention such as `PresentationCore` for `Windows.Drawing` or whatever it is. Also, MSDN links now mostly redirect to Microsoft's visual studio sales page on first visit (reset every 30 min or so), second visits go to the requisite page or 404 as is typical.

Comment: Your experiences are different than mine, then. I've always (so far, anyway) been able to find the necessary reference by starting with the documentation for the class I'm trying to use.

Comment: @KenWhite - unless you have a special version of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.sockets.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) , i see no reference there to the requisite DLL -- only the namespace which I already know -- hence the `using`, but what dll contains that namespace, is mysterious. I supposed I could just crawl the .NET framework source code itself to make a best guess, but even that doesn't really help determine which binary that namespace ends up in on compile.

Comment: @KenWhite - quoting verbatim the only blurb relating to any 'dll' reference on the page `On Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2, the Windows.Networking.dll that implements most of the classes in the Windows.Networking.Sockets namespace will fail to load unless the Media Foundation feature is enabled.` .   First >  'most'.  second >  implement this other feature/thing no clarification how/where.   third > nothing regarding any other project types. (aka, how WPF/etc can be added to winforms, but have to dig and best guess it mostly)

Comment: @Tymski - After matt pointed out the RT only thing, I noticed that you can't just copy the entire `MySql.Data` folder like you can with most projects (eg, MongoDB driver, NoSQL.net, Sqlite, and so on). You need to compare and exclude/delete a bunch of stuff from several folders. Some are in folders, some are whole folders, some are files in root of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like [Windows Runtime namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br211377.aspx).  They are for WinRT / UWP applications.

They wouldn't be available to you in a WinForms project without going through [interop](https://github.com/ljw1004/uwp-desktop/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I realized a lot of those are RT includes.  MySql doesn't make it easy to blend their driver in your code as they made the project over complex and mix .cs files for RT in the same folder as non-RT stuff -- mostly.  Working through this to eliminate the RT classes anyway, and hopefully all problems will disappear.